# How to convert all white(255,255,255) pixels to black (0,0,0) using a library function?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I don't want to convert it pixel wise, because of the complexity. Is there a library function to convert all white pixels to black at once, without affecting the other pixels?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img1 = cv2.imread('background.jpg')
```

Comment: Numpy is your best bet.

Comment: Can you provide code? Is the image a numpy array or what?

Comment: opencv has a look-up-table function

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez i have provided the code

Comment: OpenCV forum: [Replace a range of colors with a specific color in python](https://answers.opencv.org/question/97416/replace-a-range-of-colors-with-a-specific-color-in-python/) - `img[np.where((img==[255,255,255]).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,0]`

Comment: Try img[img==255]=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on OpenCV forum: [Replace a range of colors with a specific color in python](https://answers.opencv.org/question/97416/replace-a-range-of-colors-with-a-specific-color-in-python/)

```
img[np.where((img==[255,255,255]).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,0]
```

Working example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

cv2.namedWindow('window')

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

start = time.time()

img[np.where((img==[255,255,255]).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,0]

end = time.time()
print('time:', end-start)

cv2.imshow('window', img)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For image `512x341` time is `0.011182308197021484` (seconds)

---

**EDIT:** previous example with `numpy` is much faster then `for`-loops

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

cv2.namedWindow('window')

img = cv2.imread('Obrazy/images/image.jpg')

y, x, z = img.shape # `y` is first in `shape`
print(x, y)

start = time.time()

for row in range(y):
    for col in range(x):
        if all(img[row,col] == [255,255,255]):
            img[row,col] = [0,0,0]
end = time.time()

print('time:', end-start)

cv2.imshow('window', img)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For image `512x341` time is `1.5046415328979492` (seconds)

---

With

```
    if (img[row,col] == [255,255,255]).all():
```

time is `2.443787097930908` (seconds)